# Remove the charger, when my Surface Pro 2 is fully charged?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, microsoft-surface, charger

I have a Surface Pro 2. When I use it on my desk, I have access to wall outlet and I can use my charger all the time.

When the charging reaches about 100%, and the battery is fully charged, I don't know what I have to do. Continuing with power attached to the device, or removing the charger.

I have heard about damages to the battery from charging and discharging in this situation (being about 100%), and some others say that this problem is solved in the hardware.

Which one is right for Microsoft Surface? And what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to manage the surface at all. There is a microcontroller built into the hardware that will absolutely prevent unhealthy conditions for the battery.

More detail here:

http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/support/surface-with-windows-rt/hardware-and-drivers/battery-and-power

Comment: Well, that’s not entirely true either. Even after it has shut down when the battery runs out, self-discharge will eventually cause irreversible damage.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that on a long enough timeline, everything dies! I would still challenge what you're saying - the Surface has the ability to attempt recondition a battery if it finds a power source after a long period of self discharge.

Comment: Some capacity loss can be reverted, that’s correct. However, in the end, it’s physical damage. It cannot be undone. It’s the same for all Li-ion batteries. Deep discharge drastically reduces usable capacity. Because self-discharge cannot be avoided, a “0%” battery must not be left alone. That’s my point.